# filter rows if one column values matches based on another column in R data frame

Tags: r, mongodb, dataframe

As I am very new to R Programming, I need your help to find the answer

I have the below data frame as input data, now I want to return the rows which are having the same EntryName but the Sequence is different

| EntryName | Entry | GeneNames | Organism | Length | Sequence | Postion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HXA13_HUMAN | P31271 | HOXA13 HOX | Human | 388 | AAAA | 12 |
| SOX21_HUMAN | Q9Y651 | SOX21 SOX25 | Human | 276 | AAAA | 13 |
| RBM24_HUMAN | Q9BX46 | RBM24 RNPC6 | Human | 236 | AAAE | 14 |
| MZT1_HUMAN | Q08AG7 | MZT1 C13orf | Human | 191 | AAAK | 15 |
| HXA13_HUMAN | P51589 | HOXA13 HOXk | Human | 100 | ABAB | 120 |

Now I want to filter the rows for sequence AAAA and it should return the entire row where EntryName is matching with AAAA's EntryName for other Sequences

I am expecting the below output

| EntryName | Entry | GeneNames | Organism | Length | Sequence | Postion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HXA13_HUMAN | P31271 | HOXA13 HOX | Human | 388 | AAAA | 12 |
| HXA13_HUMAN | P51589 | HOXA13 HOXk | Human | 100 | ABAB | 120 |

Along with the R script, MongoDB is also helpful
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We could do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(EntryName) %>%
    filter('AAAA' %in% Sequence) %>%
    ungroup
```

Or it could be

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(EntryName) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Sequence) > 1) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
  EntryName   Entry  GeneNames   Organism Length Sequence Postion
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     <int> <chr>      <int>
1 HXA13_HUMAN P31271 HOXA13 HOX  Human       388 AAAA          12
2 HXA13_HUMAN P51589 HOXA13 HOXk Human       100 ABAB         120
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(EntryName = c("HXA13_HUMAN", "SOX21_HUMAN", "RBM24_HUMAN", 
"MZT1_HUMAN", "HXA13_HUMAN"), Entry = c("P31271", "Q9Y651", "Q9BX46", 
"Q08AG7", "P51589"), GeneNames = c("HOXA13 HOX", "SOX21 SOX25", 
"RBM24 RNPC6", "MZT1 C13orf", "HOXA13 HOXk"), Organism = c("Human", 
"Human", "Human", "Human", "Human"), Length = c(388L, 276L, 236L, 
191L, 100L), Sequence = c("AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAE", "AAAK", "ABAB"
), Postion = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 120L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
subset(df1, EntryName %in% unique(EntryName[Sequence == "AAAA"]))

 EntryName   Entry  GeneNames   Organism Length Sequence Postion
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     <int> <chr>      <int>
1 HXA13_HUMAN P31271 HOXA13 HOX  Human       388 AAAA          12
2 SOX21_HUMAN Q9Y651 SOX21 SOX25 Human       276 AAAA          13
3 HXA13_HUMAN P51589 HOXA13 HOXk Human       100 ABAB         120
```

We could also use `any`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(EntryName) %>%
  filter(any(Sequence=="AAAA")) %>%
  ungroup

 EntryName   Entry  GeneNames   Organism Length Sequence Postion
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     <int> <chr>      <int>
1 HXA13_HUMAN P31271 HOXA13 HOX  Human       388 AAAA          12
2 SOX21_HUMAN Q9Y651 SOX21 SOX25 Human       276 AAAA          13
3 HXA13_HUMAN P51589 HOXA13 HOXk Human       100 ABAB         120
```